# Simplifying$\left|\frac{z-3}{z+3} \right|=2$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to graph the following, but simplifying is the question here:
$$\left|\frac{z-3}{z+3} \right|=2$$

Now I can do this : $$\frac{|z-3|}{|z+3|}=2 $$
$$|z-3|=2|z+3|$$
$$|x+iy-3|=2|x+iy+3|$$

What manipulation do I use here? I have the answer is a circle of radius $4$ centered at $(-5,0)$

Comment: I cannot understand how the equation for a circle

Comment: can you graph $|\frac{x-3}{x+3}|-2$ to see if it is circle or not?

Comment: @Power Sorry, $z=x+iy$ is complex

Comment: ok now it is clear. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you left, *after squaring both sides* :

$$(x-3)^2+y^2=4(x+3)^2+4y^2\iff -9=x^2+10x+y^2\iff $$

$$\iff (x+5)^2+y^2=16$$

Indeed a circle centered at $\;(-5,0)\;$ and radius $\;4\;$ .

Answer (score 2):

Try writing out the definition of $|a + ib | = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$ on both sides, squaring both sides, and then simplifying.

For the left hand side, your $a$ will be $x-3$ and $b = y$.

Answer (score 2):

$$|x+iy-3|^2=4|x+iy+3|^2$$
$$|x+iy-3|^2=(x-3)^2+y^2$$
$$4|x+iy+3|^2=4(x+3)^2+4y^2$$

So:

$$(x-3)^2+y^2=4(x+3)^2+4y^2$$
$$x^2-6x+9+y^2=4x^2+24x+36+4y^2$$
$$0=3x^2+30x+27+3y^2$$
$$0=x^2+10x+9+y^2$$
$$0=(x+5)^2-16+y^2$$
$$16=(x+5)^2+y^2$$

It's an equation of circle of radius $4$ centered at $(-5,0)$.

Answer (score 1):

Square both sides of your equation and using $\left| z \right|^2 = z z^*$

$$\left|\frac{z-3}{z+3} \right|^2=4$$

$$\frac{z z^* - 6 z z^* +9}{z z^* + 6 z z^* +9} =4$$

$$z z^* - 6 z z^* +9 =4 (z z^* + 6 z z^* +9)$$

$$ 0  =3 z z^* + 30 z z^* + 27$$

$$ 0  =3 (z z^* + 10 z z^* + 9)$$

Cancel the $3$ factor

$$ 0  =z z^* + 10 z z^* + 9$$

$$ 0  = \left| z + 5 \right|^2 -16$$

$$ 4  = \left| z + 5 \right|$$

which is nothing else than the equation of a circle centred at 5 of radius 4.